# WebRTC: How to add stream after offer and answer?

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I am working on webRTC video calling. I got datachannel successfully implemented. Now I would like to add video stream to the same peer connection.

I have read that stream should be added before answer and offer. Is there a way to add stream after answer or offer?

In case I have added stream before offer or answer, how could I stop streaming and start it again when needed?

Could there be any issues in maintaining so many streams?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To add stream after creating complete signalling, the Peer connection should **renegotiate** with stream.

```
pc1.addstream(stream)
```

Then once again create offer and send it to other Peer.

Remote peer will add stream and send answer SDP.

To stop streams:

```
stream.stop();
pc1.removeStream(stream);
```

Comment: If with the first createOffer() I create a DataChannel, can I be able to use it to send the data of the second createOffer() after the addstream(), or I would loose with the second createOffer() that connection?

Comment: You can use the datachannel created using first offer.

Comment: So DataChannel connections and streams persists after calling createOffer() the second time? That's a cool feature! :-)

Comment: I found it useful: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/how-to-switch-streams.html

Answer (score 14):

In my experience, what Konga Raju advised didn't work.  I couldn't send an "updated offer" and have the video streaming actually happen.

I found that this sequence of events works for my case, in which I wish to stream video from peer 1 to peer 2.

1. set up some way for the peers to exchange messages.  (The variance in how people accomplish this is what makes different WebRTC code samples so incommensurable, sadly.)
2. On each side, set up handlers for the important signalling events.  (Some folks have reported that you need to create these handlers at special times, but I haven't found that to be the case.
   )  There are 3 basic events:

   - an ice candidate sent from the other side ==> call `addIceCandidate` with it
   - an offer message ==> `SetRemoteDescription` & make an answer & send it
   - an answer message ===> `SetRemoteDescription`
3. On each side, create the peerconnection object with the event handlers we care about: onicecandidate, onremovestream, onaddstream, etc.

   - ice candidate pops out of the peerconnection object ===> send it to other side
4. When both peers are present and all the handlers are in place, peer 1 gets a trigger message of some kind to start video capture (the `getUserMedia` call)
5. Once `getUserMedia` succeeds, we have a stream.  Call `addStream` on the peer connection object.
6. Then peer 1 makes an offer
7. Due to the handlers we set up earlier, peer 2 sends an answer
8. Concurrently with this (and rather opaquely), the peer connection object starts producing ice candidates.  They get sent back and forth between the two peers and handled (steps 2 & 3 above)
9. Streaming starts by itself, opaquely, as a result of 2 conditions:

   - offer/answer exchange
   - ice candidates received, exchanged, and handled

I haven't found a way to add video after step 9.  When I want to change something, I go back to step 3.

Comment: you can do it pretty different, for example, your step #4 getUserMedia - you can start the local video capture (preview) before even starting signaling (step 1).

I'm here reading as I have had had trouble trying to do DataChannel then AddStream... it changes things to do AddStream AFTER the DataChannel comes in as ready.

Comment: oh dear, no need to create peer connection again, we can proceed from #step 4.

Comment: It seems like it's possible: https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/docs/how-to-switch-streams.html

Answer (score -4):

MediaStream should be added to peerconnection first only then exchange of offer, answer ,candidates should be done. If the onAddStream() is called ,that mean you are receiving the remote video.

Comment: You have misunderstood the question. The OP wants to add a stream after the connection has been established.