# WebRTC: Add ice candidate error on established peerconnection

Tags: javascript, webrtc, rtcdatachannel

I am working on webRTC. I create a peerconnection between peer1 and peer2, and create datachannel on it. All things goes well.

Then I hope to add video stream base on this PeerConnection. According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16015022/webrtc-how-to-add-stream-after-offer-and-answer), I send offer and answer on datachannel. But when I send ice candidates, I got this error:

`Failed to execute 'addIceCandidate' on 'RTCPeerConnection': The ICE candidate could not be added.`

Here is the task sequence:

1. peer1 create peerconneciton and create datachannel on it
2. peer1 create offer and set local session description
3. peer1 send offer to peer2 via websocket
4. peer2 recieve offer , then create peerconnection, create datachannel on it and set remote session description
5. peer2 create answer and set local session description
6. peer2 send answer to peer1 via websocket
7. peer1 recieve answer and set remote session description

then I addstream like this:

1. peer1 get local user media and add it to peerconnection
2. peer1 create offer and set local session description
3. peer1 send offert to peer2 via datachannel
4. peer2 recieve offer and set remote session description, then get local user media and add it to peerconnection
5. peer2 create answer and set local session description
6. peer2 send answer to peer1 via datachannel
7. peer1 recieve answer and set remote session description

Is there any wrong here? When will this error happens?

Thanks for any comments!

ps: forgive my poor english

Comment: Can you add the relevant code please?

Comment: Why are you creating two peer connections? Why not just add the media to the first peer connection before creating the offer?

Comment: to @mdewitt: sorry, code is in a chat app, it`s too long

Comment: to @mattm: There is only one peerconnection.I hope to add media stream to a established peerconnection. I hope to use datachannel alone, and user can use media optional.

Comment: You do not need to send ICE candidates on an already established peer connection. The ICE candidates are to make sure the two peers can establish a connection through their potential NAT and firewalls. If you can already send data on the peer connection, ICE candidates will not do anything.

Comment: if you got answer then could you post it?